# Python print the value of specific parameter in the function

Tags: python

I only want to return and print the error when the function is called, but it seems that the whole functions are being run when I print the function.

My expected output is only:

```
false    
list index out of range
```

but I am getting:

```
false
false
false
list index out of range
```

I tried calling the function like this but did not work: print(test(error))

Question: How can I only print the error parameter and not the other parameter outside the function? Here is my code, Thanks:

```
def test(error=None, parameter1=None):
       array = []

       try:
              if parameter1 == True:
                     print("true")
                     array[0]
              else:
                     print("false")
                     array[0]
       except Exception as e:
              error = e
              return error
test()
if test() is not None:
       print(test())
```

Comment: Collect the things to print in a list, run the try/except, print the items of the list

Comment: What's the purpose of the `error` parameter? You never use it.

Comment: i thought i can use the error parameter to only print the error parameter outside the function

Comment: Assigning `error` doesn't have any effect outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running the function twice, once in the `if` statement, and then again in the `print()` statement.

If you only want to run it once, assign the result to a variable.

```
err = test()
if not err:
    print(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because python is read line by line. This means that it will check the condition for `parameter1 == True` before going onto your statement that returns an error. Restructure the code so that it checks for an error before printing out "false". Example:

```
def test(error=None, parameter1=None):
       array = []
       
       try:
              array[0]
       except Exception as e:
              error = e
              return error
             
       if parameter1 == True:
              print("true")
       else:
              print("false")

       

if test() is not None:
    print(test())
```

Additionally, the act of writing the `if test()` will call the function, which is why it printed false the first time. Then you called `print(test())` which called it a second time, resulting in two "false"s being printed out.

Comment: but what if the error is in if-else statement? Like this:               if parameter1 == True:
                     print("true")
                     array[0]
              else:
                     print("false")
                     array[0]

Comment: I am confused as to why you want to use array[0] since it does not do anything as far as I can see. If you do that and array[0] results in an error, then your script will stop and the error will be displayed in the console. The purpose of `try: and except:` is to continue running the script if there is an error.

Comment: @AlanShiah The purpose of `array[0]` is to trigger the `IndexError` that gets caught by `try/except`

Comment: Got it, so it is just specifically for triggering an error. 
@Jade Laurence C. Empleo Comments generally aren't used for discussions so if you have any further inquiries then I suggest editing your question to be more specific.